# Scope of variable from a file opened in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that opens two files which has following contents:

file1:

```
#!/bin/bash
a='Sunday'
```

file2:

```
#!/bin/bash
b=$a
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
. file1
. file2
echo $b
```

**OUTPUT :** Sunday

Here is my question:

1. What is the scope of the variable 'a' when I open file1 in the shell script?
2. How to create a shell variable with that kind of scope? Like the one below :

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   a='Sunday'
   . file2
   echo $b
   ```

Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried that? What happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sourcing a script with `.` executes the commands from that file as if they were written inline. Sourcing introduces no additional scope or environment.

Writing `a='Sunday'` has the same effect whether you write it directly or you source a script with that line: it creates a global variable visible in the rest of your script. This also explains why `file2` can see `$a`, because `b=$a` also executes inline.